# How do i get the inputted number,but repeat the same integers twice?

Tags: mathematical-programming

Imagine i get an input `123` my goal is to return `112233`.How can i get that?I can't use strings because i have to multiply that same later

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here. Try Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to string, double characters, convert back to number.

Comment: Sorry, but the question is off-topic and your answer is not the fastest solution.

Comment: It is the definitely fastest in terms of typing. Moreover, I can't detect even a infinitesimal hint from the author about time performance.

Comment: Ok, so apparently off-topic. Yes, there was no even slightest hint about the performance.